# Fill undefined elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created an empty array of for instance a length of 9 with:

```
const myArray = new Array(9)
```

I replace the array with 3 values in dynamic indexes but for a demo let's say on index 1, 5, and 7: i.e.

```
myArray.splice(1, 1, 2)
myArray.splice(5, 1, 4)
myArray.splice(7, 1, 5)
```

I have another array of 6 values that I want to fill up the undefined parts of myArray at once i.e

```
const otherValues = [2,3,1,6,7,9]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why `splice` and how do you get the values and indices?

Comment: ^ `myArray.splice(5, 1, 4)` is the same as `myArray[5] = 4`

Comment: @NinaScholz was just using splice to replace a value. Nothing concrete and I'm using Vue's key for the index when I v-for the myArray.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes that's true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to iterate over all array values, while also providing a mapping function. The mapping function can either take the first value from `otherValues` or it will use the current element if it isn't undefined. This will modify `ohterValues`, however, you can do a shallow clone of it before running Array.from using [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) if need be.

See example below:

```js
const myArray = new Array(9)
const otherValues = [2,3,1,6,7,9];

myArray.splice(1, 1, 2);
myArray.splice(5, 1, 4);
myArray.splice(7, 1, 5);
const res = Array.from(myArray, x => x === undefined ? otherValues.shift() : x);

console.log(res);
```

If you can support the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??`, you can simplify the above to be:

```js
const myArray = new Array(9)
const otherValues = [2,3,1,6,7,9];

myArray.splice(1, 1, 2);
myArray.splice(5, 1, 4);
myArray.splice(7, 1, 5);
const res = Array.from(myArray, x => x ?? otherValues.shift());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the new values array and assign the values to the empty indices.

```js
const myArray = new Array(9);
const otherValues = [2, 3, 1, 6, 7, 9]

myArray.splice(1, 1, 2)
myArray.splice(5, 1, 4)
myArray.splice(7, 1, 5)

otherValues.forEach((i => v => {
    while (myArray[i] !== undefined) i++;
    myArray[i] = v;
})(0));

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over `myArray`, filling in values from `otherValues` when the current value in `myArray` is undefined:

```js
const myArray = new Array(9);

myArray.splice(1, 1, 2)
myArray.splice(5, 1, 4)
myArray.splice(7, 1, 5)

const otherValues = [2, 3, 1, 6, 7, 9]

for (i = 0, o = 0; i < myArray.length && o < otherValues.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] === undefined) myArray[i] = otherValues[o++];
}

console.log(myArray);
```